# Script to run a program with no internet during 5sec

Tags: launch

I'm searching a way to run a specific program which will have no access to internet during 5 seconds or more and then have access to internet. Don't care the way to process as long as it's faster than disconnect my computer from internet and reconnect it. Thanks for your reply. (Don't know what tag put for this question)

Comment: You give no information at all, are you writing a program? if so, what language do you use? The easy way is ti deactivate the network card and then reactivate it but we can't give any solution without knowing exactly what it's for.

Comment: Arf sorry. I'm not writing a program, is for use a program that have a problem at launch with internet at the beginning but if I wait between 5 - 10 seconds wich it needs to launch and be on the home frame, I need internet to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a batch file with the following content in it:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
start myProgram.exe
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLED
exit
```

Of course you will need to replace **"Local Area Connection"** by the actual name of your network connection and **"myProgram.exe"** with your actual program name.

Comment: When you say "the name of your network adapter" , is the name when you write Ipconfig on the CMD or the name in 'périhperal manager' like 'Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165' ? (thanks for your help btw)

Comment: It's not the name of the card it's the name of the connection, can be "Wi-Fi" or "Ethernet 1", the name like you see it in Network Connections

Comment: Okay I found it ! but got a little problem, to use this command need to do in admin, but when I execute it in admin mode it don't find the .exe anymore :/ 

And Is there a method to only cut the connection for the program and reconnect it like now but only for the program and not the whole computer

Comment: Not I'm aware of. About the problem with the exe, using the full path should solve the problem

Comment: I already try to put the full path but.. seems to don't work :'(